# Use callbacks in Arduino with pointers to functions (will functions persist in memory?)

Tags: c++, callbacks, lambda

As I been learning Arduino (micro controllers, c++, etc) I have learned that memory is very limited. I already understand how memory works when it comes to variables. But I do not understand how memory works when it comes to functions. Since I am a backed developer I try to stay away from interrupts and instead use callback functions. Another reason why I prefer to use callback functions is because I love the visual studio IDE. I create my core functionality of whatever project I am building on a c++ project targeted for Windows. Once my algorithms/logic works the way I want it I reference those libraries on Arduino.

Anyways I am using lambdas to pass functions to my helper libraries. That way I do not use the delay function to wait for a response and I am always listening for events. **Basically my question is if it is correct to have code like this (function SendEvent):**

```
/* MyRadioLibrary.h */
// I am not including all the code of `MyRadioLibrary` because that makes it hard to 
// understand what I am asking. Instead I will try to use a lot of pseudo-code. Let me 
// know if you want me to post the code as an edit.

class MyRadioLibrary
{

public:

    static void SendEvent(int typeOfEvent, void(*onEventCompleted)(bool x))
    {
        // I have an array of pointers to functions 
        void(*onEventCompletedBuffer[10])(bool x);

        // I enqueue that event with a queue helper class 

        // Send event ....

        // DO NOW WAIT FOR RESPONSE SINCE CALL BACK IS ALREADY SAVED
    }

    static void loop() {

         // listen for radio messages
         if(radio.available()){
                // get response
                // dequeue pointer to call back   
                // execute call back
          }   
                    
    }
};
```

And my arduino sketch contains this code:

```
#include <MyRadioLibrary.h> 


void setup()  {
    // setup pins etc..
}

void loop()
{

    if (isButton1Pressed())
    {            
        MyRadioLibrary::SendEvent(1, [](bool didEventCompletedSuccessfully) {
            
            if (didEventCompletedSuccessfully)
            {
                // turn on green LED
            }
            else {

                // turn on red led
            }

        });
    }
    else if (isButton2Pressed())
    {            
        MyRadioLibrary::SendEvent(2, [](bool didEventCompletedSuccessfully) {
            
             // call back function
            
        });
    }

    MyRadioLibrary::loop(); // listen for response events. When we get one fire call back.
}
```

### Now the question

When I call the `SendEvent` function I am passing 2 things (1) an integer and (2) a pointer to a function that is the call back. The integer (1) is passed as value and that will be part of the stack of the `SendEvent` function. The pointer (2) will be stored on an array of pointers. **But what about the lambda function?** where will that be stored? Instead of using a lambda function should I declare those functions in global scope and pass the global function instead of a lambda? **Will I run the risk of the pointer (2) pointing to a function that no longer exists if I use this way of coding?**

Comment: Re “_pass the global function instead of a lambda_”: Once it's translated into machine code, it makes no difference whether it's a lambda or a regular function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions won't cease to exist. All of the code in your compiled and linked code image gets loaded into code-memory (Flash) and it stays there throughout the run, through resets, and through power-cycles, until another image is loaded over it.

Are you confusing pointers to functions with pointers to a function's local variables which occupy RAM memory, specifically within the function's stack-frame which *is* transient, being created and "destroyed" as the function gets called and returns - and successive stack-frames won't necessarily be created in the same place.